# Regular expression for Canadian ZIP codes

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to validate Canadian ZIP codes using a regex in JavaScript.

This is my code:

```
var RegEx = new RegExp("/^[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z][ -]?\d[A-Za-z]\d/");        
console.log(RegEx.test("G0A 1L0"));
```

I get `false` even though the ZIP code is valid. What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: Marked as duplicate of `Canadian postal code validation`, meanwhile, he made a delimiter error, assuming a a regex literal variant was to be used in the string passed to the constructor of RegExp(). Does anybody read past the title ? The title is inaccurate, but still ..

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out the `/` at the beginning and end of the string.

You'll also need to double up the `\` characters; otherwise, javascript interprets the string `"\d"` as simply `d`.

Assuming the entire string has to match, you probably want an end-of-line anchor at the end of the pattern as well.

```
var RegEx = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z]\\d[A-Za-z][ -]?\\d[A-Za-z]\\d$");
```